# I have n flavors of icecream. I choose k scoops, where k can be larger or smaller than n. How to generate all possible sequences?

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have 4 flavors of icecream, a, b, c, and d, and I want to get 3 scoops.

So basically I want to generate all possible 4-tuples where the sum of all elements in each tuple adds up to 3, like:

(3, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 3, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 3, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(2, 1, 0, 0)
(2, 0, 1, 0)
...
and so on, so that to generate all possible 3-scoop outcomes that can exist in menu of 4 flavors.

So for example the 5th 4-tuple I typed above would translate into an item that has 2 scoops of flavor a, 1 scoop of flavor b, no scoops of flavor c and no scoops of flavor d.

Is there a nice way of counting these things and generating them, for all cases where flavors=scoops, flavors>scoops and scoops>flavors...?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? If you allow a recursive description in terms of $k$ and $n$, there are obvious solutions. For instance when $n>0$, recursively solve for $n-1$ and all $k'\leq k$; then for each solution complete with $k-k'$ scoops of flavor $n$.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to figure out how powers of terms of polynomials of n-th degree work out. If you have (a+b+c+d)^f, I can find the coefficient for each term using the multinomial theorem but first I need to know the partition of f as powers across a, b, c, and d. I hope what I'm thinking makes sense, I'm not really good at math :~|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ denotes the number of scoops of different flavors,then since the total number of scoops $=3$$$\implies x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=3$$ where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\geq 0$. The number of solutions of this equation $={3+4-1\choose 4-1}={6\choose 3}=20$

Comment: This is the most elegant answer. Thank you sir!

Comment: No need to mention :):)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the counting formula for a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of size $k=3$ chosen from $n=4$ distinct species. The number of such multisets is 
$$\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n \\ k \end{array}\right)\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} n+k-1\\ k \end{array}\right).$$
The same formula arises in counting the number of monomials of degree $k$ constructed from $n$ variables $x_1,\dots x_n$, and [in lots of other situations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152223/why-does-mathematical-convention-deal-so-ineptly-with-multisets#comment355126_152223).

Answer (score 2):

When repetition in the selection of the objects are allowed , the number of ways of selecting $r$ objects from $n$ distinct objects is $C(n+r-1,r)$.
In your case you have 4 distinct flavors and you have to select $3$ scoops in which flavors can be repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the flavors are numbered from $1$ to $n$, starting with all $k$ scoops of flavor $1$, the following procedure will advance through all $\binom{n-1+k}k$ possibilities until reaching the choice of all $k$ scoops of flavor $n$. Repeat: find the first flavor $i$ with currently at least one scoop chosen; as long as $i<n$, replace one of those scoops by a scoop of flavor $i+1$, and all others (of flavor $i$) by scoops of flavor $1$ (the latter step does nothing if $i=1$). This generates all $n$ tuples of sum $k$ in right-to-left lexicographic order.