# Can you have negative sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I figure that since you can, of course, have members in a set, have only a single member in a set, and then have no members in a set, it seems not then a big step forward (or backwards depending how you think of it) to think of a set with negative members.

I shall elucidate. Since set theory deals with membership, and it deals not with the quantity, but the quality of those members, perhaps it be possible to have a set with negative members which subtract members from another set whose positive counterparts is contained therein.

For example, the union of the sets $A$ and $B$, where set $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and set $B =\{-3\}$ would result in the set $A ∪ B = {1,2}$.

Two notes: First, you can arbitrarily construct any set one desires, but when applied to the real world, perhaps this may be of use?; Second, the empty set seems frivolous but turned out to be quite useful, maybe the same may be said for negative sets?

As someone pointed out, and they are of course correct, the set would actually be $\{1,2,3,-3\}$. However, in sticking with the principle, is what am describing denotable?

Comment: Why don't you use {!3} (in parallel to the negation operator in C)  instead of {-3}; the latter already has an established meaning.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, what's that called? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @JimJam That is a new notation suggestion superior to the one OP used. Right?  I don't think it has been used before.

Comment: your introduction to the problem seems ill-motivated to me. You could have many members of a set, but each of them is a member "just once", which would correspond to the number $1$. No member would correspond to the number $0$ (and then you could identify a set with its characteristic function, on a suitable domain). Multisets is a different story (when a member may be counted more than once).

Comment: If we did a lot of summations on the sets, then your proposed concept would be useful. But I haven't seen much $A+B$. All I have seen so far was $A\cup B$. Just saying...

Comment: @JimJam What's that called? Gee, of course it hasn't been seen before; you just came up with these negative sets. Why don't you give it a name. I would call that operator the "anti-element" operator. It creates an anti-element which annihilates a matching element.

Comment: Sets such as the signed integers, rationals, complex numbers,..., have been introduced by starting with an existing set and giving a meaning to an illegal operation. Here you want to proceed the other way around. Following @polfosol, the negative sets proposed are not natural consequences of the $\cup$ and $\cap$ operations, and not either of the $+$ and $-$ operations (which lead to multisets).

Comment: Not possible without modifying the properties of $ \cup $, since $A\cup B = (A \cup A) \cup B = A \cup (A \cup B) = A \cup \{1, 2\} = A \neq \{1, 2\}$

Comment: It occurs to me that a *practical* way of defining rules for a multiset that can have negative repetitions can be modeled by starting with normal multisets, and having your elements have a *bias*, say, 50 of everything as your starting “empty” case.  Every set operation is followed by conditioning to cope with the bias.

Comment: You may have to think about whether you still have the property $\forall X,Y: X \in Y \lor X \not \in Y$

Comment: I have approached this problem here:  https://www.futurebeacon.com/rational.htm#Opposite  and the start is here: https://www.futurebeacon.com/rational.htm  Jim Adrian

Comment: A negative number that has the same absolute value as some positive number and is different only because it is a different type of the special type that are opposites. A pair of sets may contain numbers having opposite meaning. North versus meters south, units of weight loss versus units of weight gain, and financial debts to others versus financial debts owed to oneself.   Jim Adrian

Comment: Pairs of opposites can be notated + and - arbitrarily.  In my opinion, recognizing types is the answer. +5 is not equal to -5 only because they quantify elements of opposite type.  Jim Adrian

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you describe is isomorphic (using this word loosely) an operation (in the normal sense) of the class of all functions $f:\; S \mapsto \{-1,0,1\}$. 
For example, if $f(a) =m$, then the set $f$ has $m$ copies of element $a$.

Call $$
\mathcal{L} := \big\{ f: S \mapsto \{-1,0,1\} \big\}
$$

Then union becomes "addition and truncate to 1". I.e.,

$$
\cup : \mathcal{L} \times \mathcal{L} \mapsto \mathcal{L}  \\\\
(f \cup g)(a) := 
\begin{cases}
1,\; f(a)+g(a) \geq 1 \\\\
-1,\; f(a)+g(a) \leq -1 \\\\
0,\; \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases},\; a \in S.
$$
However, this doesn't preserve the property $f \cup (g \cup h) = (f \cup g) \cup h$.

So I have another suggestion. *Allow set elements be repetitive, even negative copies*. Then, $$
\mathcal{L} := \big\{ f: S \mapsto \mathbb{Z} \big\}
$$

Then simply define union to be addition:

$$
\cup : \mathcal{L} \times \mathcal{L} \mapsto \mathcal{L}  \\\\
(f \cup g)(a) := f(a)+g(a),\; a \in S.
$$
I don't know how to define intersection, though. 
Maybe an intersection of sets is
$$
\cap : \mathcal{L} \times \mathcal{L} \mapsto \mathcal{L}  \\\\
(f \cap g)(a) := f(a) g(a),\; a \in S.
$$
So I have preserved
$$
f \cap g = g \cap f \\\\
f \cup g = g \cup f \\\\
(f \cup g) \cap h =(f \cap h) \cup (g \cap h)
$$
Unfortunately, I did not preserve
$$
(f \cap g) \cup h =(f \cup h) \cap (g \cup h)
$$
The traditional count of element is the number of element truncated by one. If $f*$ be traditional count of $f$, then 
$$
f*(a) =\begin{cases}
f(a),\; f(a)=-1,0,1 \\\\
1,\; f(a) >1 \\\\
-1,\; f(a) <-1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: +1 I was just writing up a comment to the same effect (though less thoroughly covering the idea).

Comment: Try $\min$ and $\max$ as your intersection and union operators ... it will fulfill the distributive laws, though not the union property of the question.

Comment: Or use $(f\cap g)(a)=f(a)|g(a)|+|f(a)|g(a)$, which maps -1 inter -1 to -1 rather than 1. Still, you have the limitation of the lack of associativity of union.

Comment: Is it reasonable to summarize the math you did as "you can define anything you want, but it is difficult to define normal set operators such as union and intersection with 'negative elements' without breaking the existing properties of unions and intersections?"

Comment: @CortAmmon you put it well ;) You know Hamilton thought about for quaternion without breaking complex rules, for years! and one day reportedly he Eureka-ed at breakfast inspired by the comment by his children. (maybe fake story, anyway)

Comment: +1 Great answer shame it was later and will have trouble getting upvoted enough. We really should use a different method of answer ordering.

Comment: @DRF it took me some time to type all that down : (

Comment: @Aminopterin I understand completely. There has even been a debate about this on meta at some point. The issue is essentially that early (and reasonably good) answers get early points from people and later answers even if they are more detailed and better will have a hard time ever catching up since answers are ordered by points and many people don't necessarily scroll per the first or if they do give the first points too.

Comment: But arguably, it is reasonable to encourage early answers, and later answers also borrows ideas from early answers. It's a trade off problem; neither do we wish to deprive all credits for improvements from later answers. I guess this is how real world works....

Comment: @DRF: And my answer was even later because I don't sit around Math SE all day. Besides, what I've observed over the years (especially with popular questions) is consistent with the hypothesis that a lot of people just read the first few answers and upvote if they find them helpful, and never ever scroll to the later answers. It's to be expected since readers too don't have all day to read every single answer. But what feels most unsatisfactory with the SE system is that some **lousy answers** stay on top since mathematically incompetent readers upvote them!

Answer (score 28):

This is possible. Essentially you want to extend the definition of a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) to also include negative numbers as multiplicities. But I don't know if there is any useful application of this.

Comment: I could think of some application in computing. E.g. you have a data structure with items $A=\{a, b, c\}$ and want to update it to a new version with the "update set" $B=\{-a, d\}$, i.e. removing $a$ and adding $d$, thus $A \cup B = \{b,c,d\}$.

Comment: Is it really an extension of a multiset though?  It seems like what he's describing is more like an extension of a set in which a given element can be negatively included.  That is, whereas for a standard set, any given element is either in the set or not in the set, this adds a third option of being negatively in the set.  With a multiset, there are more options (corresponding to various multiplicities).  We can think of this new type of set (call it, say, a "mixed set") as an ordered pair of sets $C=(A,-B)$ where the second set is what we might call a "negative set" <cont>

Comment: in which union $A \cup -B$ is irreducible for disjoint $A$ and $B$ (it's the mixed set $(A,-B)$.) and otherwise reduces to $(A \setminus B )\cup -(B\setminus A)$.

Comment: @Dominik Thanks for your answer. Am not sure what a multiset is but I'll be sure to have a look into it and see if it's what am looking for :)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Generalizations for a sampling of generalizations of the notion of multiset.  See also https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093635499

Comment: @GabrielBurns Well this could be understood as multisets where the multiplicities are either $-1$, $0$ or $1$. The operations might need to be defined in a different way, depending on what you hope to achieve with them.

Comment: Another way to reach the same conclusion here would be to take $U$ to be your universe and consider $\mathbb{Z}U$.

Comment: Do not that you still can't add the number of elements this way: sets {a} and {-b} have 1 and -1 elements, but the union would be {a,-b}, and how many elements would the union contain?

Comment: If you don't allow arbitrary (integer) multiplicities, then (edit: as noted in Aminopterin's answer) unions are no longer associative since $(-X \cup X) \cup X = 0 \cup X = X$ but $-X \cup (X \cup X) = -X \cup X = 0$. That's a pretty big problem.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Right, but be careful with the idea of universes. See my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2036785.

Comment: Can confirm adjan's instinct; one way to do commutative updates in revision control views the world as made up of sets of facts which *patches* modify by "asserting" (+1) and "retracting" (-1) facts. There is a trivially commutative patch algebra on the generalized-multiset of facts, then a partial function from the gen-multi-sets to sets, where the arity of every fact is either 0 or 1. When this partial function fails, you detect this as a state conflict and demand or cook up a merge-patch to resolve it.

Comment: So for example the list [X] might be three facts: {cell1 holds X, end follows cell1, cell1 follows start}. Appends to the beginning {cell2 holds W, cell1 follows cell2, -(cell1 follows start)} and end {cell3 holds Y, -(end follows cell1), cell3 follows cell1} trivially commute. If someone else instead adds Z to the end though, it generates an obvious mergefail as "null follows cell1" gets retracted twice but asserted once. If you know the data structure you can then autosuggest the patch {null follows cell1, -(cell4 follows cell1), cell4 follows cell3, -(end follows cell3)}, which orders them.

Answer (score 9):

There is a generalization of multisets that may be what you want, which I shall call countsets but is actually nothing more than a set of pairs such that the first member of the pairs is unique and the second member of each pair is a non-zero integer. The reason I describe it this way instead of as a function from the universe (whole domain of discourse) to the integers is that in ZFC there is no function because every function has domain being a set, and there is no universal set.
$
\def\none{\varnothing}
\def\wi{\subseteq}
\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}
$

More precisely, a set $S$ is a countset iff ( $S \wi U \times \zz_{\ne 0}$ for some set $U$ and ( for each $x \in U$ there is a unique $y \in \zz_{\ne 0}$ such that $(x,y) \in S$ ) ).

For convenience let $base(S) = \{ x : (x,y) \in S \}$ and $count(S,x) = \cases{ 0 & if $x \notin base(S)$ \\ y & if $(x,y) \in S$ for some $y$ }$.

We can then define operations on countsets $S,T$ as follows:

- $S \cap T = \{ (x,m) : x \in base(S) \cup base(T) \land m = \min(count(S,x),count(T,x)) \land m \ne 0 \}$.
- $S \cup T = \{ (x,m) : x \in base(S) \cup base(T) \land m = \max(count(S,x),count(T,x)) \land m \ne 0 \}$.
- $S + T = \{ (x,m) : x \in base(S) \cup base(T) \land m = count(S,x)+count(T,x) \land m \ne 0 \}$.
- $S - T = \{ (x,m) : x \in base(S) \cup base(T) \land m = count(S,x)-count(T,x) \land m \ne 0 \}$.
- $-S = \none - S$.

These satisfy the properties:

- Normal sets embed into countsets via $S \mapsto \{ (x,1) : x \in S \}$.  [So countsets extend normal sets.]
- $\cap,\cup,+$ are commutative and associative on countsets.
- $\cap,\cup$ are idempotent on countsets (when applied to identical countsets gives the same result).
- $\none$ is the identity for $+$ on countsets; namely $S + \none = S$ for any countset $S$.
- $-$ is the inverse operation for $+$; namely $S + (-S) = \none$ for any countset $S$.
- Countsets obey extensionality; namely $S = T$ iff $count(S,x) = count(T,x)$ for every $x \in base(S) \cup base(T)$.  [The restriction of non-zero count is precisely to achieve this property, because it ensures that there is a unique representation of each countset.]

In particular we get what you want because:

> $\{(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)\} + \{(3,-1)\} = \{(1,1),(2,1)\}$.

In short, we can use non-zero integer tags for each item, instead of thinking of them as negative items, and all this can be defined and manipulated in any reasonable set theory.

Comment: Note that $S \cup T \ne S + T$ in general. One cannot mix the notions of maximum and counting without severely breaking all nice properties.

Answer (score 8):

This is an interesting question.

Clearly you have no problem with a set that contains some negative numbers, like the $B$ in your question. You're asking instead about something like a set with a negative number of elements.

That's not possible with the usual meaning of "set" so to get such "sets" you would have to invent an extension of that meaning. That kind of invention in mathematics has happened before. The numbers $1, 2, \ldots$ are good for counting. That system was usefully extended to include $0$ and the negative integers, even though it's a stretch to think of those as good for counting.

As for sets: yes the empty set turns out to be very useful. You'd want to invent "negative sets" if you stumbled across a problem where the idea would help you to a solution. The problem you started with doesn't seem to need such an invention, since ordinary sets containing negative numbers do the job when combined with a new operation on sets that creates a new set by forming a union and "cancelling" when a number and its negative match.

Comment: wait, negative numbers and set union don't work the way he described.  as has been pointed out $\{1,2,3\}\cup \{-3\}=\{1,2,3,-3\}\neq\{1,2\}$

Comment: @GabrielBurns Right. Edited thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to think of this is to first define the concept of a negative set as follows:  For any set $B$ we define the negative set $-B$, which supports the operations of union with any set $A\supseteq B$ (defined as $A\cup -B=A\setminus B$) or any other negative set (defined $-A\cup -B=-(A\cup B)$), and intersection with negative sets (defined as $-A\cap -B=-(A\cap B)$).

Once we have this definition, we can extend it to include the idea of "mixed sets" which we define as $[A\cup -B]$ for two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$.  Then union of two mixed sets can be defined as $[A\cup -B] \cup [C\cup -D]= [((A\cup C)\setminus (B\cup D))\cup -((B\cup D)\setminus(A \cup C))]$ with intersection and complementation defined similarly.

Sets with negative elements thus correspond to ordered pairs of disjoint sets.  Extending the notion of sets in this way is to me reminiscent of extending real numbers to complex numbers, as these new sets are a combination of a standard set and a new sort of object derived from a second standard set, just as a complex number is a real number combined with an imaginary number (which is derived from another real number through multiplication by $i$).

Comment: It may be worth noting that "union" will not be associative.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have $A \cup -B = (A\setminus B)\cup(-(B \setminus A))$ ? Oh sorry, you said $B$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: @Joce, yes, as explained in the next paragraph.  However, in the first paragraph, we are only defining negative sets, not mixed sets, so $A\cup -B$ is undefined if $B\nsubseteq A$.  The next paragraph defines it (just as you describe) creating the new class of "mixed sets"

Comment: $A=\{1,2\}\cup-\{3\}$, $B=\{3\}$, $C=\{3\}$. $A\cup B=\{1,2\}$, thus $(A\cup B)\cup C=\{1,2,3\}$. But, since $B \cup C=B$, $A\cup (B \cup C)=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @quid True.  It seems like for any element $x$ and any family of mixed sets $\mathcal{C}$ with $ \Gamma=[A_{\Gamma}\cup -B_{\Gamma}]=\bigcup \mathcal{C}$, we would want $x\in A_{\Gamma}$ iff $|{C\in \mathcal{C}: x\in A_C}|\gt|{C\in \mathcal{C}: x\in A_C}|$ and $x\in B_{\Gamma}$ iff $|{C\in \mathcal{C}: x\in B_C}|\gt|{C\in \mathcal{C}: x\in A_C}|$, but unfortunately there is no way to define binary union to ensure this.

Comment: @Joce thanks.  I actually got that seconds after I posted the question (which is why I deleted it), but that's a good example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: A multiplicity (positive/negative) would be needed to do this, because we are really adding/subtracting elements. Over $\{-1,0,1\}$ there is no consistent way to do it. See my answer below.

Comment: @Joce yes it would, but that would move beyond the notion of "negative sets", which is what the question is about.  Sticking to that concept, we have to be happy with a notion of union that behaves non-intuitively in some way.  This is not necessarily a problem, though, in fact it happens all the time when extending a concept from one domain to another.  Matrix multiplication, for instance, violates our intuition (from multiplication of numbers) about multiplication being commutative.  It will just depend on what you're trying to do.  If you need associative union, you need a different model.

Answer (score 4):

The '$-$' sign you define introduces a 'count' for any element, which can be present positively, absent, or present negatively. However, the operations that you would then use are the arithmetic operations plus and minus, which need the count to be over the set of integers, not just $\{-1,0,1\}$ : this is the multiplicity idea of the multisets.

In order to have such a concept, you first need to have a set of operations operating on $\{-1,0,1\}$ as the AND/OR operators are on $\{0,1\}$, or as plus and minus are on integers.

Answer (score 4):

If you seek a generalization of multisets where elements can have negative membership count (signed multisets) then this has been investigated many times in the past. One place to start learning about the history is Wayne D. Blizard's paper [Negative Membership](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093635499), which cites prior work by T. Hailperin, M. Kline, E. Fischbein, H, Whitney, R. Rado, M. P. Schutzenberger, S. Eilenberg, R Feynman and others.

See also Blizard's [The Development of Multiset Theory](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rml/1204834739) and also this [prior question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/382414/242)