# What is difference between set and family?

Tags: set-theory, terminology

I am curious of that words; 'family' and 'set.

Some use the set of the blah-blah-blah~.

However, the other some use the family of the blah-blah-blah~.

For example, we express $X=\{v_i\}_{i=1}^N$ as

1. $X$ is a set of $N$ vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_N$.
2. $X$ is a family of $N$ vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_N$.

How can I understand the diffence between them?

Comment: Where did you see the use of family for the above?

Comment: A family can contain the same element more than just once while a set can't.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172966/9464

Comment: The way I've seen it, a family is simply a set of sets. (Which is a useless notion in ZFC, but whatever.) This seems to be different than the way you're using it, though

Comment: Thank you for noticing me that there exist duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a set, all elemens (here: vectors) are necessarily different - it doesn't recognize duplicates.

Families, however, are indexed, and thus can contain the same thing (in this case, vectors) multiple times.

Comment: Easy to get understanding. Thank you